# How do I install software as a startup task in Service Fabric?

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric

When using cloud services, it was very straight forward to deploy things like the vc redistributable as a startup task for programs that depended on it.  I'm having trouble getting this to work on service fabric.  Since it needs to be installed preferably at cluster deployment (not with my application), I believe that it should be a part of the deployment ARM template.

I followed the instructions in [this link](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-windows-extensions-customscript/), but it is failing even with a simple task.

Comment: Can you add some more information about the failure?

Answer (score -1):

Similar concept exists with Service Fabric and documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-cloud-services-migration-worker-role-stateless-service#startup-tasks).

```
<ServiceManifest>
 <CodePackage Name="Code" Version="1.0.0">
   <SetupEntryPoint>
     <ExeHost>
       <Program>Startup.bat</Program>
     </ExeHost>
   </SetupEntryPoint>
...
</ServiceManifest>
```